# Об указателях в c++ и не только

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Во первых, почему то, когда я убираю строчки:

```
    int n = vec.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl << n << endl;
```

У меня появляется ошибка abort() was called. Совсем не понимаю почему так происходит.

Во- вторых, `int n = vec.size();` в теле main() присваивает n значение 0, я так понимаю это связано с тем, что vec удаляется после завершения get_vector(), а ссылка &vec ссылается на пустоту, тогда не понимаю как вернуть вектор из функции. Нужна помощь.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector <int>* get_vector()
{
    vector <int> vec;
    string current_stroke;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> current_stroke;
        if (current_stroke == "q") //Здесь завершается заполнение вектора, если в консоль ввести q
        {
            break;
        }
        vec.push_back(stoi(current_stroke));
    }
    int n = vec.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl << n << endl;
    return &vec;
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> vec = *get_vector();
    int n = vec.size();
    cout << n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << "\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Исправленный вариант:

```
vector <int> get_vector()
{
    vector <int> vec;
    string current_stroke;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> current_stroke;
        if (current_stroke == "q")
        {
            break;
        }
        vec.push_back(stoi(current_stroke));
    }
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> vec = get_vector();
    int n = vec.size();
    cout << n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << "\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `get_vector` возвращает невалидный указатель на локальную переменную, вышедшую из области видимости. `&vec` - это не ссылка, а оператор взятия адреса Возвращайте сам вектор, а не указатель.

Comment: Добавил исправленный вариант. Такой вопрос теперь: не появляется ли копия вектора? vector <int> vec = get_vector(); здесь. Получается что мы объявляем вектор в функции get_vector() потом он возвращается уже заполненный, и вот куда он потом девается? остается в памяти?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/companies/vk/articles/666330/

Comment: спасибо большое)